# How to skip over null values in Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array in which each array item is a hash with date values, as shown in my example below. In actuality, it is longer and there are about 20 dates per item instead of 3. What I need to do is get the date interval values for each item (that is, how many days between each date value), and their intervals' medians. My code is as follows:

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'

dateArray = [{:date_one => "May 1", :date_two =>"May 5", :date_three => " "}, {:date_one => "May 10", :date_two =>"May 10", :date_three => "May 20"}, {:date_one => "May 6", :date_two =>"May 11", :date_three => "May 12"}]

public
def median
sorted = self.sort
  len = sorted.length
  return (sorted[(len - 1) / 2] + sorted[len / 2]) / 2.0
end

puts dateIntervals = dateArray.map{|h| (DateTime.parse(h[:date_two]) - DateTime.parse(h[:date_one])).to_i}
puts "\nMedian: " 
puts dateIntervals.median
```

Which returns these date interval values and this median:

```
4
0
5
Median: 4
```

However, some of these items' values are empty, as in the first item, in its `:date_three` value. If I try to run the same equations for the `:date_three` to `:date_two values`, as follows, it will throw an error because the last `:date_three` value is empty.

It's okay that I can't get that interval, but I would still would need the next two items date intervals (which would be 10 and 1).

How can I skip over intervals that return errors when I try to run them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding helper functions that can deal with the types of inputs you're expecting.  For instance:

```
def date_diff(date_one, date_two)
    return nil if date_one.nil? || date_two.nil?
    (date_one - date_two).to_i
end

def str_to_date(input_string)
    DateTime.parse(input_string)
    rescue
    nil
end

dateArray.map{|h| date_diff(str_to_date(h[:date_three]), str_to_date(h[:date_two])) }
=> [nil, 10, 1]

dateArray.map{|h| date_diff(str_to_date(h[:date_three]), str_to_date(h[:date_two])) }.compact.median
=> 5.5
```

The bonus here is that you can then add unit tests for the individual components so that you can easily test edge cases (nil dates, empty string dates, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In your map block, you can just add a check to make sure the values aren't blank

```
dateIntervals = dateArray.map{ |h| 
  (DateTime.parse(h[:date_two]) - DateTime.parse(h[:date_one])).to_i unless any_blank?(h)
}

def any_blank?(h)
  h.each do |k, v|
    return true if v == " "
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I needed to put your `any_blank?` method definition above the mapping formula or else it didn't recognize the method. However, it throws the error ``any_blank?': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)`. Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: oh that's my bad, you have to pass the hash to the `any_blank?` method, ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would first just filter out the empty values first (I check if the string consists entirely of whitespace or is empty), then compare the remaining values using your existing code. I added a loop which will compare all values in the sequence to the next value.

```
dateArray = [
  { date_one: "May 1", date_two: "May 5", date_three: " ", date_four: "" },
  { date_one: "May 10", date_two: "May 10", date_three: "May 20" }
]

intervals = dateArray.map do |hash|
  filtered = hash.values.reject { |str| str =~ /^\s*$/ }
  (0...filtered.size-1).map { |idx| (DateTime.parse(filtered[idx+1]) - DateTime.parse(filtered[idx])).to_i }
end

# => [[4], [0, 10]]
```